# How to tell Typescript that lodash.filter() makes something non-null?

Tags: typescript, lodash

I recently started using Typescript, and I use strict mode.  There are a lot of cases where I have a list of nullable values, and I use _.filter() to remove the nulls.  E.g.,

```
const users: {id: number, name: string | null}[] = getUsers()
const lowerCaseNames = _(users)
  .filter(user => !!user.name)
  .map(user => user.name.toLowerCase())
  .value()
```

That doesn't work because Typescript still thinks that user.name can be null, so user.name.toLowerCase() isn't valid.  Instead, I've had to split up the chain over multiple variables and use a typecast, both of which are unfortunate:

```
const users: {id: number, name: string | null}[] = getUsers()
const usersWithNames: {id: number, name: string}[] = _.filter(user => !!user.name) as {id: number, name: string}[]
const lowerCaseNames = _.map(usersWithNames, user => user.name.toLowerCase())
```

Is there any way to tell lodash/typescript that `.filter()` gets rid of the nulls without a typecast or without breaking up the chain?

Thanks!

Comment: did you npm install --save @types/lodash ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/lodash

Comment: Can't you just "bang" it? `user!.name.toLowerCase()`

Comment: "did you npm install --save @types/lodash ?"

Yes

Comment: "Can't you just "bang" it?"  Yes, but in general, I regard typecasting (including non-null typecasting) as a "do it when necessary" kind of thing that should be avoided when possible (because it reduces the number of errors that typescript could catch for me)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a type guard inside `filter`

```
type User = { id: number; name: string | null }

const haveName = (user: User): user is User & { name: string } => user.name !== null

const users: User[] = []

const lowerCaseNames = _(users)
  .filter(haveName)
  .map(user => user.name.toLocaleLowerCase())
  .value()
```

Comment: Since the original question asked to keep the function inline, why not declare `haveName` inline and save the extra named function:

```ts
const lowerCaseNames = _(users)
  .filter((user: User): user is User & { name: string } => user.name !== null)
  .map(user => user.name.toLocaleLowerCase())
  .value()
```

Answer (score 2):

[@Asaf Aviv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60329369/1715579) is on the right track with type guards.

Here's a generic version that works even if you don't want to specify a type for `User`:

```
declare const users: {id: number, name: string | null}[];
const notNull = <K extends string>(key: K) =>
    <T extends { [k in K]: T[K] }>(val: T): val is T & { [k in K]: Exclude<T[K], null> } =>
        val[key] !== null;

const lowerCaseNames = _(users)
  .filter(notNull('name'))
  .map(user => user.name.toLowerCase())
  .value();
```